# Java ReqExp получить атрибуты тега

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день, есть строка:

```
<div id= "10"    class  =   " .mcp   " align="100px" i11d= "10"    c11lass  =   " .mcp   " alig1n="100px">
```

Пробую с помощью маски `[a-zA-Z]+\\s*=\\s*\".+\"` вытащить все атрибуты. Использую такой код:

```
check("[a-zA-Z]+\\s*=\\s*\".+\"", testStr3);
static  void check(String reg, String testStr)
{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(reg);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(testStr);
    if(m.matches())
        out("Group " + m.group()); // out <=> System.out.println();
    else 
        out("No matches with group");
    out("While find");
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(testStr.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
    }
    out("Done");
}
```

При этом `m.matches()` всегда `false`. Соответственно `m.group()`никогда не выполняется, а `while` печатает просто строку со всеми атрибутами. Вопрос вот какой, как получить все атрибуты по отдельности, а не в одной строке?

Comment: Попробуйте так:  `/([a-zA-Z]+)\s*=\s*\"(.+?)\"/g `

Comment: ^ И вероятно хвост  - `\"([^\"]+?)\"/g`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
    check("[a-zA-Z]+\\s*=\\s*\".+\"", testStr3);
    static  void check(String reg, String testStr)
    {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(reg);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(testStr);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Group " + m.group());
            System.out.println(testStr.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
```